# iPhone / iPad: Reply to Email with embedded image -- Image gets replaced with image.png

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mobile-mail

Here is the case:

- User Receives an email with and embedded image in the body of the email.
- replies to the email and the embedded image gets removed from the body.
- forwards the email.. its fine the image is retained in the body.

does anyone know of any work around for this. this only happens when working from mobile device (iphone or ipad) using iOS 7 mobile mail.

Replies from outlook retains the image. We have exchange 2010 on the backend using activesync to connect devices.

Can reply be made to work like forward ?

Answer (score 1):

This is default behaviour. If you reply, the sender already had the image thus it's not needed to send it over and over again.
If you forward it, you're (most likely) sending it to a different person who did never see the content before, which makes it relevant to add the image.
You cannot change this, except if you find any 3rd party plugin.

If you really want to reply the image, just forward the mail and add the emailaddress of the sender back in the "To" field.

Answer (score 0):

First try to forward and click on Include Images. Ensure that the images are showing up.
Then Cancel this message.
Now try to Reply All.
This time the images in the email chain should show up.

Sounds silly, but it worked for me. I am on iOS 8.1.2.